# Motherboard running rather hot while gaming

Tags: performance, motherboard, cooling

- Case: Antec 1200
- Mobo: Gigabyte GA-X58A-UD3R
- CPU: Intel i7 950 (stock cooler)
- GPU: EVGA GeForce 570 GTX
- RAM: 2x 2 GB (4 GB total) DDR3 dual-channel Corsair
- OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

This is my first build and it's brand new. I had no problems putting it all together in a few hours one evening and I consider myself to be pretty good with computers. Not to brag or anything like that! Just saying I've been fiddling with them since I was in diapers and I have a good amount of experience under my belt, just not with certain things yet.

Recently while playing many of the latest games maxed out without a hitch my motherboard has been running hot and like anyone who's ever built a computer it scares the life out of me. I checked HWMonitor and saw that my motherboard sometimes reached temperatures of around 52 - 78c (the number 78 obviously being what's scaring me). I was wondering if such a temperature is normal and if not what the problem could be.

Air flow in my case is phenomenal and besides having to ship back a faulty GPU and reseat my CPU my first build has been a very large success which I am enjoying tremendously. There is literally almost no dust in my case due to it being very new as previously mentioned and my RAM sticks are in the correct slots for dual-channel mode. My cable management is pretty great in my opinion with only cables from my PSU lingering in the bottom of the case. At any given opportunity I ran my cables behind my mobo. Air flow should definitely not be a problem because my CPU only goes up to about 60c and my GPU only goes up to about 80c.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: How are you checking your temperatures?

Comment: As I see it, first step would be to determine which part of the motherboard is hot. Check heatsinks and see if any of them are very hot. It could be normal, but on the other hand maybe manufacturer forgot to put thermal paste/pad under heatsink for whatever northbridge is called these days or something like that. Maybe the motherboard needs an additional fan fomewhere for its cooling?

Comment: I'm checking my temperatures via HWMonitor, typoknig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a motherboard where the "PWM" temperature sensor continually reads **10°C hotter** than the *CPU*, hitting 85°C when gaming. Considering it's been like that for 3 years, I think you're fine.

Realistically, most mosfets are specced up to a maximum junction temperature of 125°C, so the real worry is baking the electrolytes out of the capacitors. Assuming you mobo has solid caps, you should be fine.

Comment: I understand and I agree. I was thinking the same thing but seeing as it's my first build, it's brand new, and I spent a lot of money on it, I'm kinda paranoid about these things. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's good to be paranoid sometimes.